# Is data at risk if Salesforce restricts access as a result of overdue invoice?

Tags: community, data, licenses, access

Does anyone know if data is at risk if Salesforce restricts access as a result of an overdue invoice? We have a number of projects in our Sandbox, as well as vital data in our Org. If restricted, can this be compromised/deleted?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176370&language=en_US#:%7E:text=Active%20or%20paid%20organizations%20have,DELETED%20and%20flagged%20for%20deletion.):

> - After an active or paid subscription with Salesforce expires or is terminated, the organization is placed in the LOCKED status. While the organization is LOCKED, you will be unable to access your Account.
> - Active or paid organizations have a 120-day grace period in the LOCKED status. Salesforce retains your organization data during this 120-day period as a courtesy.
> - Once the 120-day period lapses, the organization will be marked as DELETED and flagged for deletion. You will no longer be able to retrieve data past this point.

So, you have approximately 4 months to either request a data export or renew your licenses before you'll lose your data. Salesforce is a very kind and understanding company. While they can't give you, say, free perpetual licenses, they will generally do nice things like allow a one-time data export if you decide to leave, and give you plenty of time to renew if that is your intent. If you need time, a one-time data export, or to renew your licenses, contact your Account Executive or the Sales team.